# What are the components of a language lesson?

Tags: teaching

What I understand is, language teaching has two aims:

1. Skills [Reading, Writing, Speaking, and Listening] development
2. [Linguistic competence](https://teflpedia.com/Linguistic_competence) development

So, each language lesson **should** cover at least one skill component and at least one linguistic component.

**Am I correct?**

Is there a 3rd component called literacy?

E.g. [Literacy](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/literacy#Teaching_literacy) includes:

1. phonological awareness
2. decoding
3. fluency
4. comprehension
5. vocabulary.

Comment: What should be part of every language lesson depends on the language teaching method you espouse. So the answer is: it depends. (Also: literacy covers both reading and writing.)

Comment: @Tsundoku *What should be part of every language lesson depends on the language teaching method you espouse.* --- kindly elaborate and post an answer.

Comment: *literacy covers both reading and writing.* --- literacy not only includes reading and writing. Does it?

Comment: Regarding language teaching methods: there is a long list of [language-teaching approaches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_pedagogy) that will influence what you include in individual lessons and how. Regarding literacy: if you think it includes more than reading and writing, please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: @Tsundoku, edited.

Comment: Ah, I see you had early literacy teaching in mind. I was thinking of higher-level literacy skills. That explains the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Tsundoku, so, what is your answer then?

Comment: Could you add whether you are thinking of foreign language teaching or first-language teaching? What age group are you thinking of?

Comment: @Tsundoku, I am thinking of L2, and elementary education.